# Unable to pass data in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, .net, model-view-controller

I am having trouble with passing the data from my view to the controller to verify the data. The `ModelState.IsValid` is false all the time. I don't know what else can I do over here.

Model:

```
public partial class Testing
{
    public int LoginID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string EmailID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public int TaxID { get; set; }
    [Required]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    public string CorporationName { get; set; }

    public static bool IsUserValid()
    {
        HttpContext context = HttpContext.Current;
        if (context.Session["LoginID"] != null)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
            return false;
    }
}
```

Controller:

```
public ActionResult ForgotLoginId()
{            
    return View();
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult ForgotLoginId(Testing ForgotLIDAuthentication)
{
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            using (SUPRTestingDBEntities2 db = new SUPRTestingDBEntities2())
            {
                var obj = db.SUPRTesting.Where(a => a.EmailID.Equals(ForgotLIDAuthentication.EmailID) && a.TaxID.Equals(ForgotLIDAuthentication.TaxID)).FirstOrDefault();

                if (obj != null)
                {
                    Session["LoginID"] = obj.EmailID.ToString();
                    Session["EmailID"] = obj.TaxID.ToString();
                    return RedirectToAction("LIDAuthentication");

                }
                else if (obj == null)
                {
                    return View();
                }
            }
        }            

        return View();         
}        

public ActionResult LIDAuthentication()
{
        if (Testing.IsUserValid())
        {
            return View();
        } 
        else
        {
            return RedirectToAction("ForgotLoginID");
        }
}
```

View:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Corporation Registration";
}

@using (Html.BeginForm("ForgotLoginID", "Corporation", FormMethod.Post))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true)

    if (ViewBag.Message != null)
    {
        <div style="border: 1px solid red">
        @ViewBag.Message
        </div>
    }

    <div style="height: 30px; width: 20%; font-size: large; text-align: center; margin-left: 40%; margin-right: 40%; margin-top: 5%; margin-bottom: 46px; background-color: deepskyblue; color:white" class="auto-style9">
        <b>Forgot Login ID</b>
    </div>

    <div style="height: 475px; width: 50%; text-align: left; margin-left: 25%; margin-right: 25%; margin-top: 10%; margin-bottom: 46px; background-color: #FFFFFF; border-color:black">
        <span style="margin-left:10%"></span>
        <label for="Label1" style="width:20%; color:red; font-weight:normal !important">* Required Entry</label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <span style="margin-left:10%"></span>
        <label for="Label5" style="width:20%">Email Address:</label>
        <label for="label6" style="color:red"><b>*</b></label>
        <span style="margin-left:9%"></span>
        @Html.TextAreaFor(a => a.EmailID)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.EmailID)
        <span style="margin-right:9%"></span>

        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <span style="margin-left:10%"></span>
        <label for="Label1" style="width:17%">Tax ID:</label>
        <select id="taxid" style="width:10%">
            <option value="fein">FEIN</option>
            <option value="ssn">SSN</option>
        </select>
        <label for="label2" style="color:red"><b>*</b></label>
        <span style="margin-left:20%"></span>
        @Html.TextAreaFor(a => a.Password)
        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(a => a.Password)
        <span style="margin-right:9%"></span>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <span style="margin-right:9%"></span>
        <label for="label6" style="color:darkblue; font-weight:normal !important">(Enter Federal Tax ID) or (SSN) 9 numbers, do not enter dashes or spaces.</label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <span style="margin-right:9%"></span>
        <label for="label6" style="color:darkblue; font-weight:normal !important">If you don't know Email Address, then please call Helpdesk at 1-800-000-0000</label>
        <br />
        <br />
        <span style="margin-left:20%"></span>
        <button type="submit" style="width: 20%; color: white; background-color: deepskyblue; border-color:black" value="SubmitRequest" name="Submitbtn"><b>Submit</b></button>
        <span style="margin-left:20%"></span>
        <button type="reset" style="width:20%; background-color:deepskyblue; color:white; border-color:black"><b>Clear</b></button>
        <br />
        <br />
        <br />
        <span style="margin-left:10%"></span>
        <label for="label6" style="color:red; font-weight:normal !important; visibility: hidden">Email Address or the Login ID does not match. Please verify and enter the details again.</label>
    </div>
}
```

I was advised my view must provide fields for, at a minimum, all the required fields in your model. Can someone help me with this.

Comment: Have you inspected the `ModelState.Errors`?

Comment: For one thing, you `<select>` for TaxID needs `name='TaxID'`

Answer (score 0):

In your view you should add (name="") to select :

```
        <select id="taxid" name="TaxID" style="width:10%">
        <option value="fein">FEIN</option>
        <option value="ssn">SSN</option>
        </select>
```

Also in model TaxId is (int) but in select box values are (string), you change int in model to string, Also it's better to add (Required) on select,because in models it's Required

Comment: The dropdown here has no expectation. It is just there for now.